# Center a picture after adding it to Word using Active Qt

Tags: c++, qt, com, ms-word, activeqt

I'm generating a Word document via `Qt's Active Qt` module.

I'm able to write to the document, specify the "style" for that writing (bold, italic, justified aligment, etc.) and query diverse parts of it.

Right now I'm trying to display a picture and position it right in the center of the page.

For inserting the picture:

```
QAxObject word( "Word.Application" );

QAxObject* activeDocument = word.querySubObject("ActiveDocument");
QAxObject* activeWindow = activeDocument->querySubObject( "ActiveWindow" );
QAxObject* selection = activeWindow->querySubObject( "Selection" );

selection->dynamicCall( "Collapse(int)", 0 );
const int pos = selection->dynamicCall( "End" ).toInt();

QAxObject* shapes = activeDocument->querySubObject( "Shapes" );
QAxObject* shape = shapes->dynamicCall( "AddPicture(QString,bool,bool,float,float,float,float)",
                     picPath,
                     true, true );
```

This inserts the picture on the left of the page. In `Word`, I can insert the picture, select it and specify its alignment (centered, in my case), but I'm not able to do this via code.

I tried to set the pic's anchor to the center, but it still appears at the left of the page:

```
shape->querySubObject( "Anchor" )->querySubObject( "ParagraphFormat" )->setProperty( "Alignment", 1);    // 1 == wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

and:

```
shape->querySubObject( "Anchor" )->dynamicCall("InsertAlignmentTab(int)",1); // 1 == center
```

Also, note that when I open the created document with the inserted images, if I select one of the pictures, **I can't center it**; whereas using the *Insert* menu, I can select the picture and center it.

Is there a way to center any picture I insert into `Word`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to center the picture in question.

```
QAxObject* shapes = selection->querySubObject( "InlineShapes" );
QAxObject* inlineShape = shapes->querySubObject(
            "AddPicture(const QString&,bool,bool,QVariant)",
             picPath, false, true )
;
inlineShape->dynamicCall( "ScaleHeight", height );
inlineShape->dynamicCall( "ScaleWidth", width );

selection->querySubObject( "ParagraphFormat" )->setProperty( "Alignment", 1 );

QAxObject* range = shape->querySubObject( "Range" );

const int start = range->property( "Start" ).toInt();
const int end = range->property( "End" ).toInt();
selection->dynamicCall( "SetRange(int,int)", start, end );
selection->dynamicCall( "Collapse(int)", 0 );

selection->querySubObject( "ParagraphFormat" )->setProperty( "Alignment", 3 );
```

Instead of querying the `Shapes` object, I now query the `InlineShapes` one. This is an important, since now I'm able to use the selection object (which now is pointing to the position of the inserted picture) and specify it's alignment, via the `ParagraphFormat` subobject.

After that, I update the selection with the picture `Range` to start typing after the pic and set the alignment back to justified.

Comment: Is there a way to replace Qstring image path with QImage,QPixmap or something similar ?

Comment: Don't know. I never had to use the image directly. I don't have the code at hand, so I can't try it either. :(

Answer (score 1):

When you are inserting image into Word it can float above text or be in paragraph. (Text Wrapping)

You should check whether image was inserted into paragraph or is floating above.

```
*Select Image -> Formatting -> Wrap Text*
```

It appears to me that you set style for paragraph alignment, but image is floating above text.

Comment: Hi. The text wrapping is Word's default. It's the same as when I insert a picture via the toolbar. Nevertheless, you'r answer helped me to start looking for paragraph alignment.